# Insert data from handsontable into mysql database using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, handsontable

I am creating an HTML page using Handsontable to have an excel like experience .I have to insert the data into mysql database using PHP 5.1.6 at server side.I am stuck here Please help.

I am not able to understand ,how it will work.

Initial part of .js code :

```
 <script>
    var data = [[]];
             var container = document.getElementById('create_table');
             var hot = new Handsontable(container,
          {
           data: data,
           minRows: 30,
           minCols: 13,
           maxRows:100,
           copyPaste:true,
           colHeaders: true,
           rowHeaders: true,
           rowHeaders: true,
           contextMenu: true,
           dropdown: true,
           colHeaders:["Testcase Name","Cell Name","Customer","Flops","Title","Status","Mfix CCR(open/close)","Scenerio-Brief Desc
    ription","Expected Results","CCR Status","CCR No.","Remarks","Testcase Path"]
          // minSpareRows: 1,
         });
</script>
```

I have looked for a solution online , but couldn't find a simpler solution.I will be highly thankful if anybody can help...

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626957/connect-handsontable-to-mysql-server/41890114#41890114

Comment: I saw that answer,but was unable to understand the solution as i don't know about json.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=I+am+not+able+to+identify+error+-+create.php%3a91+Uncaught+SyntaxError%3a+Unexpected+identifier